# Moving domain controller from Samba to Windows Server 2008

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, migration, windows

I need to migrate an existing Active Directory from Samba to Windows Server 2008. It's easy as add a new Windows Domain Controller, wait for AD replication and turn off the linux machine?

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you are asking.

Comment: What version of Samba are you running?

Comment: I don't have this information yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure:  I'm a Windows person, not a Samba person.

However, that's pretty much it for adding a new Windows domain controller in an active directory environment, and from what I read that's pretty much it for adding a new Windows domain controller to a Samba 4 domain.

The Samba docs do have a warning about DNS interoperability:

> If you wish to join a new Windows domain controller to a Samba domain,
>   then you should use the 'dcpromo' tool on the Windows machine. Please
>   see the normal instructions for installing dcpromo on Windows, with
>   the exception that you should not check the 'DNS server' option box
>   when it is offered. Right now you should either use Windows for DNS,
>   or use Samba and bind9 for DNS. Mixing the two can work, but it is an
>   advanced topic that is beyond the scope of this howto.

That's the only possible trickiness I see.

http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO#Joining_a_Windows_Domain_Controller_as_an_Additional_DC_in_a_Domain